# Как перевести код JavaScript в Python

Tags: javascript, python

Есть код на JavaScript:

```
function getQuote(symbol, apikey) {
 var requestOptions = {
   method: 'GET', 
   redirect: 'follow'
 }; 
 if (apikey) {
   requestOptions.headers = {
     Authorization: apikey
   } 
 }
 var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:"   + symbol + "/quotes?format=TV", requestOptions)
 var json = res.getContentText()
 var data = JSON.parse(json)
 return json
}
```

Хочу перевести его в Python, не понимаю как быть с if apikey, получается так:

```py
def getQuote(symbol, apikey):
    requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    }
    if apikey {requestOptions.headers = {Authorization: apikey}}
    res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:" + symbol + "/quotes?format=TV", requestOptions)
    json = res.getContentText()
    data = JSON.parse(json)

    return json
```

Comment: обратите внимание на стандарты оформления: https://python-school.ru/blog/pep-8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests

def getQuote(symbol, apikey):
    requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    }
    if apikey:
        headers = {Authorization: apikey}
    res = requests.get("https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:" + symbol + "/quotes?format=TV", requestOptions, headers=headers)
    json = res.json()
    return json
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не используйте форматирование текста через +. 
есть много других способов что работают гораздо лучше 
res = f"https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:{symbol}/quotes?format=TV"
res1 = "https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:{0}/quotes?format=TV".format(symbol)
res2 = ("https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:%s/quotes?format=TV" %symbol)
res3 = ("https://api.alor.ru/md/securities/MOEX:%(symbol)s/quotes?format=TV" % {"symbol" : symbol})